# Prevent all pages -> page -> visualization filter to apply

Tags: powerbi

I need to create a report with several pages filtered out to some entities (whatever) to display some consumption charts. I made a filter at "all pages" level to modify all pages at once. Working fine!

However I would like to have average for all entities displayed so member of a specific entity can compare to others without having their details.

To do this, I found it would be convenient to have a way to prevent :

- visualization to apply "page" and "all pages" filters
- "page" to apply"all pages" filters

In other words to prevent filters cascading.

Can this be made ?

Thx,

Answer (score 0):

To stop filter interaction you have to click on your visual and then go to `Format > Edit Interaction`. Now you see on every other visual a diagram and a circle. If the diagram is grey the interaction is active, is the circle is grey the interaction is inactive.

For your second problem you can activate the sync slicers pane (`View > Sync Slicers`). However this just works for slivers and not for filters which are in the filter pane.

At the moment it is not possible to stop or edit interactions from filters within the filter pane. They are applied always like it is stated: For a visual, page or all pages.